# Automatic weight paint error when trying to rig a bow

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I get the "bone heat weighting failed: could not find solution for one or more bones" whenever I try to parent the armature to my bow mesh with automatic weights. I already tried different things including:

- Removing Doubles
- Recalculating Normals
- Removing all Vertex Groups
- Adding the Decimate modifier

I can't find out what's causing the error.

Here is the [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4IBaPLW2b2iZ29IcG1xLWJsdzg/view?usp=sharing).

What causes this and how to I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning usually appears when there is a bone that doesn't have anything near it.

The bone that is supposed to pull the string is the likely culprit.

I suggest applying with *envelope weights*, (which I was able to do after ridding myself of the pesky draw bone) and getting on your thinking shoes for some intensive weight painting time. Sometimes you just need to weight paint because the computer's automatic isn't 'human' enough. This can take *forever*, so don't do it before a mid-day appointment.

Also, your string is just kinda stuck into the bow; you might want to separate it from the bows shaft and then join them using a **boolean** modifier set to union.